# How to depoly a Node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have installed npm locally and used it to install Bower, Grunt, Polymer & Yeoman. But I am still a little confused as to what Node.js actually is.

Back in the day I used to setup an Apache server locally, install phpMyAdmin and get to work on my project. I could then take the SQL database & the entire file directory for my project that included php, html, css etc. files and upload to my server and it would run.

I have noticed that PHP is not the way to go anymore, and that everyone seams to be running JS frameworks like Angular, Backbone & Ember, also Polymer looks interesting but I am not sure if it's a framework.

So my question is **how do I deploy something built with node.js**? e.g. a dashboard website/app built in Angular, Backbone, Ember or Polymer.

I am also guessing that SQL would not be the way to go anymore, but a noSQL option would be, such as PouchDB or Mongo? I really don't know how people like to store data with these new frameworks, maybe they still use SQL?

Can I simply copy the process of PHP & SQL and upload the SQL database & then the file dir and it will run on the server?

I have used firebase to deploy a polymer website/app, but **I would like to know if I could use a standard web host instead of firebase or heroku**.

Comment: This question is too broad. SO is not the right place to ask. See [ask].

Comment: You should have asked how to deploy an app, not mention the reasons why you want to try node, your reasons are off by freakin' parsecs, but w/e, if we were all correct all the time, world would suck,

Comment: I guessed it might be a little broad. So do I have to rewrite and post again ?

Comment: SO is the place to ask if you have a discrete problem which, most of the time, can be represented by a [mcve].

Comment: I am just blown away by the amount of frameworks & platforms to choose from and what's the difference between them and PHP & MySQL.

Comment: Do you mean the wrong category to ask about this? Or the wrong website?

Comment: At that point, you'll have to read the docs, reviews, etc, and choose one for each part of your project. Then if you need specific help with one, come back and ask on that.

Comment: If there's a huge number of frameworks to choose from, that doesn't mean those frameworks are any good. You deploy a node project just like any php project. Since you used Apache and probably never heard of `php-fpm` then this process is probably lost on you, seeing that `php-fpm` works almost exactly like node does. Write the code, stick it on a server, run `node yourfile.js` or whatever entry point there is and that's **basic** deployment (there's a lot to this of course, this is the simplest case).

Comment: @JamesKing it's simply too broad and this type of question is bound to start a flame war, it's not correctly formed. You should have read some more docs on node, the difference between what you're used to (apache and php) is that you don't need a web server like apache / nginx in front of it, but can use one.

Comment: Apologies about the broadness. Thank you for your answers. What is a flame war?

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 common ways to go about this. You can think of them in terms of **client app** and **server app**.

## Server

If you're just creating a Node.js server, you may want to use the library [Express](http://expressjs.com/) (which is a wrapper around Node.js's `http`) in order to initialize a server. Then when you upload your source code to, say, AWS EC2 or Heroku (just as an example), you tell your startup script to invoke your server (if you server initialization code is in `./server.js`, for example, you'd tell your EC2 or Heroku script to run `node server.js`).

## Client app

There are a lot of tools to compile client apps (static sites), many of which work with Node.js: for example, Bower and Webpack. In this case, Node.js is only responsible for running this build tools and compiling your app for you. Then, it's as simply as copying the compiled static files into your hosting provider (like AWS S3, for example). Outside of the scope of the answer, but you can use continuous integration tools like Codeship or CircleCI in order to compile and upload those static files to your hosting provider automatically.

## Hybrid

If you want Heroku to serve a static site, you can set it up in a way where Node.js is actually running a server *that serves static files*. This is a combination of the 2 approaches above because you need to actually be running an `http` server inside of Node.js that is responsible for serving your static content. You can also have an API server embedded in the same place, but a common practice is to have a separate API server somewhere else (separation of concerns).

A couple additional comments:

> SQL would not be the way to go anymore, but a noSQL option would be, such as PouchDB or Mongo?

False. SQL and NoSQL both have their benefits. This is out of scope, but on a high-level, there are differences between schemas (whether maintained on the database server or the client server), operations likes joins, etc. (which plays into scalability), and the features of each individual database provider: for example, Redshift is a SQL database based on Postgres that uses columnar storage which is good for running, say, sum operations across gigantic datasets. There are Node.js drivers for it, you just have to pick your poison.

> I would like to know if I could use a standard web host instead of firebase or heroku.

I wouldn't refer to a host using the term "standard", as essentially all hosting providers do the same thing: serve content. If you're using Node.js, you have many choices for hosting providers: AWS S3, AWS EC2, Heroku, Bluehost, and myriad other providers.

Comment: Thank you for your response. That has really cleared things up for me! Taking your example of a client app, lets say built in Angluar. How would I store data? Do the hosting providers you mention have the option for a SQL or noSQL database?

Comment: @JamesKing, no problem, glad it helped!

Comment: @JamesKing yeah it just depends on how you wanna store it. There are cloud providers for MongoDB for example. If you use Heroku, you can add all kinds of databases onto it: MongoDB, Postgres, etc.

Comment: @JamesKing alternatively if you're hosting provider doesn't provide DB integrations, you can choose a separate cloud provider (like AWS or mLab), and just make sure your server communicates with it.

Comment: I see, thank you. What would be the difference between a cloud provider eg. AWS, Heroku, Firebase and a host like GoDaddy web hosting?

Comment: @JamesKing not much. Like I said, they all do the same thing, just some providers give you additional options like directly integrating databases.

Comment: Thanks. So basically cloud is just a fancy name? I noticed that the providers that are involved with native apps tend to use this phrase more?

Comment: @JamesKing Something like Heroku is more a platform (PaaS) with its own hosting being transparently with amazon services.

Comment: @JamesKing cloud doesn't really mean anything special :) it's a fancy word for some computer somewhere else. They all refer to themselves as cloud providers, to distinguish from the fact that you don't need to run your servers on your own local equipment.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can simply copy the files unless you write a script that will automatically call `npm init` (or whatever your startup scripts are) when the files have changed.

As long as you have shell access on your server you can probably use Apache or nginx as a reverse proxy for your node app, and set up a push-to-deploy system with git fairly easily.